# Wikipedia extractor problem ValueError: cannot find context for 'fork'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, extractor, wikimedia-dumps

My aim is to get plain text (without links, tags, parameters and other trash, only articles text) from wikipedia xml dumps (https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html). I found WikiExtractor python script on GitHub (https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor). After downloaing and installing it (i use PyCharm IDE, Windows 10) i tried to get it started with

`wikiextractor -cb 250K -o extracted D:\Wiki_dumps\ruwiktionary-20211120-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2`

but then (after preprocessing) i got following error

> raise ValueError('cannot find context for %r' % method) from None
> ValueError: cannot find context for 'fork'

I tried to change the parameter in the following function from "fork" to "spawn" (advice from the internet)

`Process = get_context("fork").Process`

but this only leads to

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedWriter' object

I have no idea how to fix it or what it might be related to

Here is full stack trace:

> INFO: Preprocessing 'D:\Wiki_dumps\ruwiktionary-20211120-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2' to collect template definitions: this may take some time.
>
> INFO: Preprocessed 100000 pages
>
> ...
>
> INFO: Preprocessed 2300000 pages
>
> INFO: Loaded 36839 templates in 209.9s
>
> INFO: Starting page extraction from D:\Wiki_dumps\ruwiktionary-20211120-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Shurup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>
> File "C:\Users\Shurup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\Users\Shurup\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\wikiextractor.exe_*main*_.py", line 7, in
>
> File "c:\users\shurup\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\wikiextractor\WikiExtractor.py", line 640, in main
> process_dump(input_file, args.templates, output_path, file_size,
>
> File "c:\users\shurup\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\wikiextractor\WikiExtractor.py", line 359, in process_dump
> Process = get_context("fork").Process
>
> File "C:\Users\Shurup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 239, in get_context
> return super().get_context(method)
>
> File "C:\Users\Shurup\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 193, in get_context
> raise ValueError('cannot find context for %r' % method) from None
>
> ValueError: cannot find context for 'fork'

Here is stack trace with "spawn" instead of "fork" parameter

["spawn" parameter stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxiSO.jpg)

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace

Comment: Done. Perhaps the problem is with the OS, but in that case I would be very grateful for any advice on running this script on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes fork context in multiprocessing is only supported in UNIX, context spawn should work on Windows, But you did not post the stack trace for the ```TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedWriter' object```

Comment: Done (.jpg in the end of question). If we talk about UNIX, is it enough to have just UNIX emulator on Win10 and how i can run this script from such OS?

Comment: I think this is a known issue in the wikiextractor community the best bet is to downgrade python and run it in a UNIX environment, I don't have an idea about UNIX emulators but you can spin up a virtual box with any Linux distro and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it in Docker. It works like a charm.

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim

WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install wikiextractor

COPY Wikipedia-20211212095544.xml /app/

CMD python -m wikiextractor.WikiExtractor --output /app/output /app/Wikipedia-20211212095544.xml
```

Build: `docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t wikiextractor:latest`
Run: `docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source="$(PWD)\output",target=/app/output wikiextractor:latest`

Make sure you have an `output` folder in your current working directory.

Comment: build command did not work for me, but docker build . worked

Answer (score 0):

I directly pip install wikiextractor locally, and then pip install wikiextractor==0.1, and it can be extracted normally.

Comment: (base) (venv) PS E:\python_project\financialkg\venv\Lib\site-packages\wikiextractor> pip install wikiextractor==0.1

Just like this.